# Remove parent div if child div contains a certain data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since, I'm doing this dynamically, I have to check whether the main div matches a certain `user-id`. If it does, then dive into it and do the extra work. Let me show you what i'm talking about.

```
<div class="col-md-6 user-card-holder" data-user="2">
  <div class="col-xs-2 single-card">
    <div class="house" data-house="hearts" data-value="q">Q-hearts</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are many `div's` having the classname `user-card-holder`. I have to check the specific one with the `data-user` attribute. Now what I'm checking is:

If a div contains `data-house` with the value of `hearts` and also `data-value`   with the value of `q`, then remove that div along with it's parent. Here parent means the `div` having the class `single-card` and not the `user-card-holder`

I have tried using `filter()`. Maybe I'm doing something wrong here.

```
 $('.user-card-holder[data-user='+ card.user +'] div div').filter(function(){

     var div = $(this).data('house') == card.house && $(this).data('value') == card.number;
      return div.parent()


     }).remove();
```

I have seen answers which shows to remove the element based on data attribute, but not it's parent.

Comment: Select the child with `'.user-card-holder[data-user='+ card.user +'] div[data-house=hearts][data-value=q]'` and traverse up to the parent with `.parent()`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
// this finds all <div> elements with a
// 'data-house' attribute equal to 'hearts' and a
// 'data-value' attribute equal to 'q':
$('div[data-house=hearts][data-value=q]')
  // traverses to the parent of the matching element(s):
  .parent()
  // removes the parent element(s) from the DOM:
  .remove();
```

Alternatively, if you're searching an ancestor dynamically to find the appropriate element(s) to remove, which seems to be the case on a re-reading of your question:

```
// finds <div> element(s) with the class of 'user-card-holder'
// and the 'data-user' attribute equal to the value of the 'card.user'
// variable, and finds the descendant <div> element(s) matching
// the selector used above:
$('div.user-card-holder[data-user=' + card.user + '] div[data-house=hearts][data-value=q]')
  // traverses to the parent of the descendant element:
  .parent()
  // removes the parent element of that descendant:
  .remove();
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- jQuery:

  - [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
  - [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove).

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
removeCardFromUser(2);

function removeCardFromUser(id) {
    $('.user-card-holder').filter(function(){
        var user = $(this).data('user');
        if (user === id) {
            $(this).find('div').filter(function(){
                var house = $(this).data('house');
                var value = $(this).data('value');
                if (house === 'hearts' && value === 'q') {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

It looks for a div with class 'user-card-holder' and data-user = {given id} and then looks for its descendants with data-house = 'hearts' and data-value='q' and deletes its parent.

David's answer would suffice though! :)